# YML Parsing error - symfony documentation

Tags: parsing, symfony, yaml

In order to allow users to upload documents on my website, I am trying to add form validation on a symfony2 application. According to this doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html , I should create a validation.yml file with this syntax :

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author
    properties:
        bioFile:
            - File:
                maxSize: 1024k
                mimeTypes: [application/pdf, application/x-pdf]
                mimeTypesMessage: Please upload a valid PDF
```

I have tried to type/edit this file in a lot of ways, yet I always get a parsing error when the file is executed :

```
 Unable to parse in "\/***\/***\/dev\/***\/src\/***\/***Bundle\/Resources\/config\/validation.yml" at line 1 (near "***\***\Entity\Author").
```

I tried to test this code with this online YML parsing tool : http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/, and it says the colon on line 3 just after "properties" is wrong :

```
Output
ERROR:
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 13:
      properties:
                ^
```

What am I missing here? Why is the YML syntax used in symfony documentation not accepted by this online parser? Note that I am aware of the tab indentation vs. space indentation for .yml files.

Comment: Yaml is not tab indented but space indented, can this solve your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not... This was my first thought but it didn't solve it. I tried editing or re-writing the code with different editors, or through command line. I also tried saving it a text file and then renaming it as a .yml, nothing will do... My best guess now is that symfony uses a custom YML syntax but I can't seem to find any documentation online that describes this.

Comment: If you add `:` at the end of `Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author` it should work (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation)

Comment: Yes that was it! This colon was missing on the code snippet of this page : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html Have a nice day cheesemacfly many thanks.